# Javascript knockout binding nested objects not working

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm am relatively new to the use of the knockout javascript library. I'm having a problem getting an observable property which is an object of another object. Here is my code:

```
function Customer(id) {
    var self = this;

    self.customer_id = ko.observable(id);
    self.custnum = -1;

    self.busname = ko.observable("");
    self.address = "";
    self.city = "";
    self.state_id = "";
    self.zipcode = "";
    self.cnt_sal_id = "";
    self.cnt_first_name = "";
    self.cnt_last_name = "";
    self.cnt_title = "";

    //alert("customer: " + self.customer_id());

}


var CustomerEntryViewModel = function(date) {
    var self = this;

    self.last_update = ko.observable(date);
    self.customer = ko.observable(new Customer(""));

    self.addCustomer = function (id) {
        var c = new Customer(id);
        self.customer = c;
        alert("New id: " + self.customer.customer_id() + " num: " + c.custnum);
    }

    self.customerSearch = function () {
    }

    self.editCustomer = function (customer_id) {
    }

    self.save = function(customer) {    
    }           
}
```

How do I go about binding to the properties in the Customer object. I try to to use typical javascript dot notation like so: customer.customer_id

Here is the html that binds the data:

```
<div class="field-input" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <input type="text" id="customer_id" style="width:100%;" 
        data-bind="jqxInput: { placeHolder: 'Customer #', value: 
                               customer().customer_id, height: 21, width: 208, 
                               minLength: 1, disabled: true }"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Since `customer` is an observable, you have to *unroll* it in your bindings.  So it would be something like:

```
<div data-bind="text: customer().address"></div>
```

And similarly, this

```
alert("New id: " + self.customer.customer_id() + " num: " + c.custnum);
```

would be

```
alert("New id: " + self.customer().customer_id() + " num: " + c.custnum);
                          //     ^ unrolled
```

Comment: @user2864740 - ah, this http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-controlling-descendant-bindings.html  Seems really cool.  Added to my reading list :)

Comment: Adam, thanks for the response. Believe it or not, this part works: alert("New id: " + self.customer.customer_id() + " num: " + c.custnum); However, the same reference does NOT work in my html bindings.

Answer (score -3):

Try this, should be helpful :

```
<div class="field-input" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
  <input type="text" id="customer_id" style="width:100%;" data-bind="value: customer().customer_id, disabled: true" />
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, but please stop adding answers that duplicate existing ones.