# knockout options binding, nested optionsValue

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

lets assume that our array of options contains objects such as this

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Wisconsin",
    attr: {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

so with knockout bindings we can write something like this,

```
<select data-bind="
    options:availableStates, 
    optionsText:'name', 
    optionsValue:'id', 
    value:selectedStateId">
</select>
```

however, if I wanted the `optionsValue = attr.color` the value is empty

https://jsfiddle.net/xxhc9wwh/1/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript knockout binding nested objects not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503805/javascript-knockout-binding-nested-objects-not-working)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can resolve this using a function in place of a string. From Knockout's [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

> Similar to `optionsText`, you can also pass an additional parameter called `optionsValue` to specify which of the objects’ properties should be used to set the value attribute on the `<option>` elements that KO generates. **You can also specify a JavaScript function to determine this value. This function will receive the selected item as its only argument and should return a string to use for the `<option>` element’s value attribute.**

```
optionsValue: function(self) { return self.attr.color }
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xxhc9wwh/2/).